# How to migrate AX 4.0 (SP2) on Oracle to a SQL server platform

Tags: sql-server, oracle, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I'm facing a problem with MS Dynamics AX 4.0 SP2 while I migrate data from oracle (version 10) to SQL Server 2008 R2 and I am using SSMA tool to transfer data.

The AX system with Oracle is customized in 3 layers 'var', 'cus', 'usr'. I have already done these below steps:

- Install new AX system with fresh SQL Server database
- Copy the all application files from the current system to the new system

This works for create new schema of table when I synchronize dictionary on AX system.

When I compare schema of some tables in SQL Server with Oracle, I have found that there are some columns that have disappeared in SQL Server.

The reason is if not match schema together, we can’t migration data from Oracle to SQL Server.

Could you please help me with problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are any of the field names keywords? Renaming some fields is to be expected if the name is a keyword in SQL but not in oracle.

Also, are you absolutely sure that your license and configuration options are the same? AX (pre-2012) will delete the tables and fields in your database if you don't have the license key, or you have the configuration key turned off

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have already checked difference, I have found some difference. I dint have license for SQL server on Dynamics AX also.